# Child theme does not appear in theme selection

Tags: themes

I'm trying to add a child theme to my wordpress installation. The theme the child should be based upon a theme called "nostalgia-landing" which is installed and works properly. I created a new folder called "nostalgia-custom" and added the the *style.css* with the following content:

```
/*
Theme Name: Nostalgia Custom
Description: Nostalgia Custom is a responsive WordPress landing page.
Author: QuanticaLabs and Christoph Halang
Author URI: http://themeforest.net/user/QuanticaLabs?ref=QuanticaLabs
License: GNU General Public License version 3.0
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
Version: 2.0.2
Template: nostalgia-landing
*/
@import url("../nostalgia-landing/style.css");
```

However, the theme selection in admin panel does not show my child theme and says "You only have one theme installed right now.". This is not true since there are the default themes. When I delete the child theme folder the default themes appear again in the selection.

Did I miss anything? Any ideas guys?

Regards,

Chris

Comment: Can you add a directory listing or screen grab of files and folders in wp-content/themes ?

Comment: Can't post images directly since I'm a newbie but here is a link [Screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/87e22046-b848-4c07-bfa0-638c9b833127/cb6f9972047baef0d0ed8b2166019dd7/deep/0/WordPress%20Child%20Theme%20Folder%20Structure.png)

Comment: Thanks, looks good, now we would need to see the contents of nostalgia-landing/style.css.

Comment: Since I bought the parent theme it is a rather long file :-/ I tried removing the import statement in my style.css with no effect, still no child or default theme visible.

Comment: Screen grab of Appearance page ( /wp-admin/themes.php )?

Comment: Here you go [Screenshot Appearance Page](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/ffbc1680-cb44-44fb-b241-82557217e984/54180696c4978781f0bb8763bfc0bf07/deep/0/Manage%20Themes%20%E2%80%B9%20Medieninformatik%20in%20Weimar%20%E2%80%94%20WordPress.png)

Comment: Weird, perhaps Nostalgia doesn't support child themes. Perhaps check with the vendor.

Comment: Mhh, I tried to copy the theme and rename the folder and the titlein the style.css. No sucess.

Comment: Let's try to narrow the scope of the problem. Change `Template:` from `nostalgia-landing` to `twentytwelve` - i.e. `Template: twentytwelve`, and verify if the Child Theme appears properly.

Comment: Tried to set the template value to twentytwelve as suggested: Does not help. Still no themes visible in the appearance section. Another thing worth mentioning: I tried to add an empty folder named "empty" without any style.css file inside to the themes folder.Then I removed my nostalgia-custom child theme. The result is the same. Do you guys experience the same issue when adding an empty folder to the themes directory?

Comment: To be more precise: Adding empty folders to my themes directory breaks the selection of themes

Comment: Solved it, see my answer for details... Hope this whole discussion helps some other newbie! Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved: My child themes folder and the enclosed files had permission 750 instead of 644 set. Changed the permission and everything is working!

Comment: Good, glad you found your solution. Once you're able, accept your answer as the correct one, so that others with the same problem can benefit.

Comment: Good tip to check permissions! However note that files should normally be 644:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Two things come to mind:

1. Is `nostalgia-landing` a child theme of something (Nostalgia perhaps)?  WordPress doesn't allow grandchild themes -- you can't have a child theme of a child theme.  (Check the `style.css` file in the `nostalgia-landing` theme -- if there's a `Template:` line, then `nostalgia-landing` is a child theme.  If that's the case, you'll need to make `nostalgia-custom` a child of the original theme.)
2. Is this a WordPress Multisite installation?  If it is, you need to Network Activate both your child theme and the parent theme.  If you don't activate the parent theme, you can't use the child theme.

Comment: `style.css` is the only file required to create a child theme

Comment: Good point. Back to two.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your thoughts on my issue, here's what I think: 1) No, there is no "template" line in nostalgia's style.css file. 2) I don't know exactly what an MultiSite installation is but my wordpress installation is the only one on the server and was recently installed.

Comment: [This is Multisite.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite)  If you installed WordPress and didn't turn on Multisite, then that's not the issue.  Your best bet might be to contact the theme developers that made your parent theme, and ask them about your problem.